# WebMethod return as String (without <?xml tag)

Tags: asp.net

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true, XmlSerializeString =  false)]
public string RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
```

returning value started with `<?xml`. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's doing that because it's a SOAP Web Service and that is what is expected from a SOAP Web Service.  If you want to return *just* plain text back to the client, I'd create an ashx to process the request manually.

Like this (this is the default Generic Handler scaffolding)

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Test : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```